# Material viewport display glitches when using alpha less than 1

Tags: 3d-view, transparency

I modeled this eyeball and I wanted to make the cornea sligthly transparent. I never used this before but I thought I would use the viewport display color since it has an Alpha channel. But as soon as I drop the alpha to any other value than `1`, this happens :

[image]

[image]

I use Blender 3.0 but the problem also appears also in 2.93.4 but not in 2.7.

**How to reproduce the problem**

For me, this happens in 2.93 and 3.0.
I duplicated the default cube, moved it next to the old one, gave the second cube a duplicated material and change the viewport display color of one of them to something with alpha less than `1`.

[image]

I would like to know if anyone can reproduce the problem and/or knows where it comes from and/or how to eventually fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it worked before 2.79, but doesn't after it has to do with GPU compatibility - https://code.blender.org/2019/04/supported-gpus-in-blender-2-80/

Comment: Yes, the problem doesn't show on 2.7. Is there any fix for it or it's just something we need to deal with?

Comment: Just have to deal with it, I'm afraid. Blender overhauled GPU integration for 2.8+ and some just didn't make the cut when it comes to compatibility, unfortunately